# Identify controller/buttons using javascript Gamepad API

Tags: javascript, gamepad, chrome

Using the Gamepad API, or possibly some third party device mapping, is there a way I can associate buttons (gamepad api gives buttons by a numeric key value) to their controller counterparts?

For example, when using an xbox one controller with the PC, the "x" key is given by chrome as `2`. I'd like to use the controller id/key value to show a picture of that happen to help new users.

It seems like this isn't something native to the gamepad API, but I'm not seeing any third party libs for it.